# Should users confirm email address

Tags: web, membership, email-verification

I want to build user registration into a website. Could some one advise if it's necessary to setup an email confirmation system? I feel this could greatly annoy the user.

Answer (score 0):

I find this very annoying, If you have to do it you should also consider giving users an option to authenticate themselves again social sites like twitter or facebook.

Comment: This is not an answer.  If you want to contribute to a question, post as a comment.  If you have a question of your own, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of reasons why it’s important to verify an email address:

- **Security**: being able to send your users reset instructions, or any important updates about the site, etc.
- **Spam Prevention**: By forcing a user to confirm
  their email before performing any substantial actions on the website, will help combat spam and your website from being filled with fake users.
- **Avoiding Shutdowns from Email Delivery Systems**: Systems like Amazon Simple Email Service will flag your website as not trustworthy after a certain amount of emails are sent through their system that end in bounces. Personally have had this happen because I wasn’t monitoring them in my own system architecture.
- **Payments**: if your website requires payments of any sort, you’ll want a method to contact the user.
- **Newsletters**: if you want to let your users know of some action related to your company or website, you’ll want to accurately know how many people you’re emailing… or even be able to email them and not just a trashcan full of fake emails.